# java 8 for solaris has no libnpjp2.so?

Tags: solaris, java-8

I downloaded java 8(64bit) for solaris from oracle official site and installed it on my solaris machine. But when I tried to enable this java8 in browser, I can not find the file libnpjp2.so under the jre/lib folder. then How to enable java 8 for firefox under solaris ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Compatibility Guide for Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html) lists this as a planned end-of-support change:

> **[Features Removed from JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html#A999476)**
>
> **Synopsis**:    Removal of 32-bit Solaris
>
> *...*
>
> The 64-bit binaries do not contain deployment tools such as Java Web Start and Java Plug-in,

Comment: then can I install the Java Web start and plug-in separately for java8? another strange things is, the java8 for linux still has the file libnpjp2.so

Comment: I believe you would need to either install the ones from java7 for Solaris, or build them from the OpenJDK sources, as Oracle does not make them.   (A 64-bit plugin can't run in a 32-bit Firefox, and last I saw, Mozilla doesn't support 64-bit builds of Firefox.)